# Best way to keep the last N rows by a certain column

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let's say I have a table of employees and I want to record their monthly salary inside a table and I only want the latest 12 rows to be there.

I know I can do something like this every time I want to insert a salary record:

```sql
INSERT INTO salary (employee_id, amount, timestamp) VALUES (id, amount, current timestamp);
DELETE FROM salary WHERE employee_id=id ORDER BY timestamp ASC OFFSET 12;
```

But is there a better approach?

Akina suggested:

> Update the most ancient record instead of insert/delete. The amount of records will be constant, and you'll store the most recent records.

That seems like it could be really inefficient? As I am developing an application, I need to check if there are 12 rows or not, if there isn't then insert, if there is, I need to update all the rows in the table and move the data on the bottom row and update the first row - that'll take a lot of queries. I need to use automation, I need a better approach to improve performance.

I tried to read from the official reference and search the google to find clear details about [`INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html), but unfortunately I can't understand how they could help in my situation.

Can someone give me an example approach please?

Comment: IODKU and REPLACE both rely on an a primary key or unique key. I can't see a logical formation of such in your structure. For 12 rows I think your solution is ok, just wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: @danblack Yeap, that's what I understood from the documentation and as I couldn't find out how it can be better than my approach, I thought I'm missing something. Thanks by the way.

Comment: *That seems like it could be really inefficient?* One-query solution which guarantees that the amount of records is always 12, is less efficient than the solution with 2 queries and without records amount "not above 12" guarantee? Really?

Comment: @Akina One query? Can you demonstrate how can I do it using one query? If you are able to do it using one query, that's the title of my question actually and you can answer it.

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I get it now, I think it is as efficient as my current approach, because your method also needs 2 queries right? One to select the count of rows (Probably fetch the most out dated "timestamp" and probably add a primary key to the table), one to either insert a new row or update the oldest row.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table (done 1 time)

```
CREATE TABLE salary 
( employee_id INT NOT NULL, 
  amount DECIMAL(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL, 
  ts DATETIME DEFAULT '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
              ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

Insert 12 records for new employee (done 1 time when creating a new employee)

```
INSERT INTO salary (employee_id)
SELECT @new_employee_id
FROM ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION .. UNION SELECT 12 ) numbers;
```

Add new data (done monthly)

```
UPDATE salary
SET amount = @new_amount
WHERE employee_id = @employee_id
ORDER BY ts ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: But it's actually a table for my users and employee was just an example, I don't want unnecessary records for all the users who haven't that triggered the log. Imagine thousands of users registering and those logs created without they doing anything.

Comment: You know? I didn't know "OFFSET" doesn't work on DELETE statements and nobody even mentioned it to me. Your method is the best method mixed with a select query. Thank you.